# android:list view layout to display the report

Tags: android, android-listview

I need to create the list view to display the report,that will contain the header of list with border and below that it will contain the list view ,image link will explain you better,please also note the horizontal borders!
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax43T.jpg)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a layout xml for a cell
2. Create a layout xml for a row
3. Create a layout xml where you define a row (for the header) and the ListView below that
   3.a. Alternatively you can use the ListView's addHeaderView(View v) method
4. Create a custom adapter and override the getView method. Check if for every other row (position % 2 == 0) and change the row's color

I've made a sample project, you can download it form [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/296580/Test.zip).

1.) Create a layout xml for a cell

res/layout/cell.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/item_light_bg"
  />
```

If you want your rows to be the same width specify layout_width="0dp" and layout_weight="1".

2.) Create a layout xml for a row

res/layout/list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<include
    android:id="@+id/firstCol"
    layout="@layout/cell"
  />
<include
    android:id="@+id/secondCol"
    layout="@layout/cell"
  />
<include
    android:id="@+id/thirdCol"
    layout="@layout/cell"
  />
<include
    android:id="@+id/fourthCol"
    layout="@layout/cell"
  />
<include
    android:id="@+id/fifthCol"
    layout="@layout/cell"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

3.) Create a layout xml where you define a row (for the header) and the ListView below that

res/layout/main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/list_item"
    />
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

4.) Create a custom adapter and override the getView method. Check if for every other row (position % 2 == 0) and change the row's color

```
public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    ...
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout)super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (position % 2 == 0)
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 55));
        else
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(22, 22, 88));
        return v;
    }
    ...
```

Also, you may want your ListView to be static (eg. not clickable and selectable). To do this override the isEnabled method in your Adapter.

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: it is what i want,thank you very much for this explanation and code